# How do I disable comment fetching in Liferea?

Tags: rss, liferea

While reading lifehacker, Liferea freezes on every single post loading the comments. Frankly, I do not really care for these, so how can I disable the loading all together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit strenuous if you have a lot of feeds, but when you select a feed (you have to do this for every single feed), click the **Feed Menu**, *or* right click to get the **context menu**, click **Properties**, and then select the **Advanced** Tab, and click the option to ignore comment lists.

---

> [image]

Comment: The lifehacker thread was the one that slowed down the most, so this was as easy fix. Thanks! (Btw. what Theme is that you have there?)

Comment: @queueoverlow: Glad it worked for you ^^!

I have a mix of themes in that screenshot: One is the emerald theme for the "A New Hope" with a modded button order, and then a theme called Soothe with the selected items colour changed. I think I was using a faenza theme with it as well.